# One localStorage.setItem invocation is getting a typescript error, but the previous near-identical line is not, regarding unassignable parameters

Tags: typescript

In the following block of code:

```
const setSession = (access?: string | null, refresh?: string | null) => {
    if (access) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', access);
        window.localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refresh);
        axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${access}`;
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
        localStorage.removeItem('refreshToken');
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
    }
};
```

The `setItem` line regarding `accessToken` has no typescript errors, whether or not the line regarding `refreshToken` exists.

However, I'm getting a typescript error on the `setItem` invocation for `refreshToken`. The error is:

```
Argument of type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2345

    41 |     if (access) {
    42 |         window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', access);
  > 43 |         window.localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refresh);
       |                                                     ^
    44 |         axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${access}`;
    45 |     } else {
    46 |         localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
```

Why am I getting the error on the second line? I also get the error if I change the function definition to:

```
const setSession = (access?: string | null, refresh: string | null = null) => {
```

Then the error becomes:

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2345

    41 |     if (access) {
    42 |         window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', access);
  > 43 |         window.localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refresh);
       |                                                     ^
    44 |         axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${access}`;
    45 |     } else {
    46 |         localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
```

What's happening here? Are the two invocations of `localStorage.setItem` not identical in terms of types?

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example. Without that, I would guess `refresh` is typed (explicitly or otherwise) to `string | null`, and `setItem` only takes a `string`.

Comment: I think the issue may be that in your if statement you're checking that access is truthy, but refresh could still be null/undefined. I think if you check that refresh is truthy before you call setItem, it will probably fix it.

Comment: @Bets was correct, good point I should have seen that. If you add your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @CalebJay cheers! Added it as an answer in case it might help anyone else.

Comment: Cheers, also this way the question is "closed" and far less people will come here thinking it still needs an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like setItem is expecting to get a string, and while access is confirmed to be "truthy", refresh could still be "falsy", and is therefore throwing an error.

This should fix it:

```
const setSession = (access?: string | null, refresh?: string | null) => {
    if (access) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', access);
        if (refresh)
            window.localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refresh);
        axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${access}`;
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
        localStorage.removeItem('refreshToken');
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
    }
};
```

Comment: I put the refresh check in the initial if statement, aka `if (access && refresh)`, but yeah this fixes it.

Comment: Right, that's what I would have done as well, but not knowing the rest of the code, and on the off-chance that you might call it somewhere with an access token but not a refresh token, I figured separating them was the safer way to go! ;)